# why does wp core install say table 'wp_options' doesn't exist

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

Im using wp cli on my `bedrock` directory setup and have the files in the wp dir. now installing the core using

`wp core install --url=xxx --title=xxx --admin_user=xxx --admin_email=xxx --admin_password=xxx`

and gives

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'xxx.wp_options' doesn't exist in`

The target db is empty with no tables.
Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe the WP CLI command  `wp core update-db` will help you create missing tables.

Comment: It gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem was I was using php8. The same wp cli command worked properly in php74

Comment: I'm encountering this same error while using php 7.3.33, 7.4.25, and 8.0.13 

I don't think it's php related.

Comment: For posterity: I read in all the wp-config.php values from a .env file. When I changed the table prefix from a custom one to 'wp_', the command started working. I deleted the database and changed the prefix back to my custom one, and it is still working. All I can think is that something in my .env file was being pulled in incorrectly or something was corrupted. `wp config get` looked fine, though. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Downgrading php from 8.2 to 7.4 actually did fix it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Got the same error! And this is the correct fix! Thanks a lot for your help.